# Join two tables together and condense multiple rows in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables as follows:

TableOne
- RawDataId int (pk)
- TimeStamp DateTime
- BuildingID int

TableTwo
- RawDataId int (pk/fk)
- MeterId int (pk)
- Value real

The MeterId is not unique and repeats multiple times (but always in equal number). The two tables join together no problem. I am able to select the top 15 rows and order the by time stamp, giving me the latest value for each meter (15 in total, each with a time stamp). However, I also need to get the Value of each meter from a previous time (exactly 1440 and 1439 minutes earlier) - if that makes any sense.

So after the query is run, I need a table with the columns from TableOne and TableTwo, but with two additional columns for ValueB and ValueC (B been the value 1440 minutes earlier, and C 1439 earlier). Ive been playing around with his all day and most of last night, and I'm slowly losing the plot.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks peeps.

--- Update

I've included the actual table schema below, together with some sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableOne](
[RawDataId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[BuildingId] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [TableOne_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableTwo](
[MeterId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[RawDataId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Value] [real] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [TableTwo_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

The sample data for the last 30 records from TableOne:

```
RawDataId, TimeStamp, BuildingId
21677   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21678   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21679   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21680   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21681   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21682   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21683   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21684   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21685   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21686   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21687   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21688   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21689   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21690   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21691   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1
21662   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21663   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21664   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21665   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21666   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21667   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21668   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21669   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21670   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21671   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21672   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21673   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21674   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21675   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
21676   2012-05-16 00:02:00.000 1
```

Sample for TableTwo:

```
MeterId, RawDataId, Value
15  21691   7722613
14  21690   908944
13  21689   4982947
12  21688   3821899
11  21687   6
10  21686   0
9   21685   0
8   21684   5761656
7   21683   4240048
6   21682   1541372
5   21681   283223
4   21680   1.298603E+07
3   21679   388137
2   21678   876121
1   21677   0
15  21676   7722615
14  21675   908944
13  21674   4982947
12  21673   3821899
11  21672   5
10  21671   0
9   21670   0
8   21669   5761656
7   21668   4240052
6   21667   1541372
5   21666   283223
4   21665   1.298604E+07
3   21664   388137
2   21663   876122
1   21662   0
```

A meter reading is written to the tables every 1 (hence the time stamp). When select the top 15 records (sorted by TimeStamp, to give me the latest values), I also need to get the values of that meter 1440 and 1439 minutes ago (relative to the latest TimeStamp). I hope this makes it clearer.

So far, my SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 15 * FROM (Select TableOne.[RawDataId], 
[TimeStamp], BuildingId, MeterId, `enter code here`Value 
FROM [TableOne]
INNER JOIN TableTwo ON
TableOne = TableTwo) as PS
ORDER BY [TimeStamp];
```

The query gives me the follow, but I need the additional two columns with the value of the meter 1440 and 1439 minutes ago, relative to the TimeStamp:

```
RawDataId, TimeStamp, BuildingId, MeterId, Value
21677   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   1   0
21678   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   2   876121
21679   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   3   388137
21680   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   4   1.298603E+07
21681   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   5   283223
21682   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   6   1541372
21683   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   7   4240048
21684   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   8   5761656
21685   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   9   0
21686   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   10  0
21687   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   11  6
21688   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   12  3821899
21689   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   13  4982947
21690   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   14  908944
21691   2012-05-16 00:03:00.000 1   15  7722613
```

Comment: A small sample of data and what you want your results to look like would be helpful

Comment: What does "1440 minutes earlier" mean? Just subtracting the value, or finding a row that has subtracted value in it? Is the "previous time" known in advance, or you just need the previous row with whatever time is in it (and 1440 and 1439 minutes are just examples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a data (and maybe query) sample, it's really hard to understand the problem.  If I'm understanding correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT
(
SELECT TOP 1 Value
FROM TableOne t1 join TableTwo t2 ON t1.RawDataId = t2.RawDataId
WHERE t1.RawDataId IN (
SELECT RawDataId FROM TableTwo WHERE MeterId = tbl.MeterId
) and TimeStamp = DATEADD(mi, -1440, tbl.TimeStamp)
) as ValueB,
(
SELECT TOP 1 Value
FROM TableOne t1 join TableTwo t2 ON t1.RawDataId = t2.RawDataId
WHERE t1.RawDataId IN (
SELECT RawDataId FROM TableTwo WHERE MeterId = tbl.MeterId
) and TimeStamp = DATEADD(mi, -1439, tbl.TimeStamp)
) as ValueC
FROM TableTwo tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are always going to have values for 1440-minutes and 1439-minutes prior, something like this might work:

```
SELECT TOP 15 
      TableOne.BuildingID
    , TableOne.RawDataID
    , TableOne.TimeStamp
    , TableTwo.MeterID
    , TableTwo.Value
    , TableTwo1439.Value AS ValueB
    , TableTwo1440.Value AS ValueC
FROM TableOne
JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.RawDataID=TableTwo.RawDataID
JOIN TableTwo TableTwo1439 ON TableTwo.MeterID=TableTwo1439.MeterID
JOIN TableOne TableOne1439 ON TableTwo1439.RawDataID=TableOne1439.RawDataID AND TableOne.TimeStamp=DATEADD(MINUTE,-1439,TableOne1439.TimeStamp)
JOIN TableTwo TableTwo1440 ON TableTwo.MeterID=TableTwo1440.MeterID
JOIN TableOne TableOne1440 ON TableTwo1440.RawDataID=TableOne1440.RawDataID AND TableOne.TimeStamp=DATEADD(MINUTE,-1440,TableOne1440.TimeStamp)
ORDER BY TableOne.Timestamp DESC
```

Otherwise, you can still use the same approach, but might need to tweak it to use OUTER JOINs instead...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could try something like this:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT
    t1.RawDataId,
    t1.TimeStamp,
    t1.BuildingId,
    t2.MeterId,
    t2.Value,
    x.Diff AS TimeStampId
  FROM (SELECT BuildingId, MAX(TimeStamp) AS TimeStamp FROM TableOne GROUP BY BuildingId) t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1440 UNION ALL SELECT 1439) x (Diff)
    INNER JOIN TableOne t1 ON t.BuildingId = t1.BuildingId
                          AND t1.TimeStamp = DATEADD(MINUTE, -x.Diff, t.TimeStamp)
    INNER JOIN TableTwo t2 ON t2.RawDataId = t1.RawDataId
)
SELECT
  RawDataId,
  TimeStamp,
  BuildingId,
  MeterId,
  Value           = [0],
  Value1440MinAgo = [1440],
  Value1439MinAgo = [1439]
FROM data
PIVOT (
  MAX(Value) FOR TimeStampId IN ([0], [1440], [1439])
) p
```

That is, I'm assuming here you want to account for various BuildingIds, since that column is present in your output. If you only want a specific one, you could rewrite the `t` subselect like this:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableOne WHERE BuildingId = @Id ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) t
```